# Emacs ESS SAS: Automatic windows splitting to display program, log, and listing

Tags: emacs, sas, ess

I would like to set up Emacs /ESS so that upon pressing F3 to run a program (on server), it would split my windows into 3 sections. Ideally, it would have one larger window on one side for the SAS program and two half-height windows on the other side containing the LOG and LST files.

I have been using C-x 2 and C-x 3 to split my Emacs windows manually, then cycling through the buffers in each window to get the result I described. This works, but it would be great to have this be automated in some way.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to define a command (with `defun`) to do what you
need (you'll be using `(split-window-below)` and `(split-window-right)`
         instead of `C-x 2` and `C-x 3`). Then you bind F3 with that command with:

`(global-set-key (kbd "<f3>")   'your-command-name)`